# Is it possible to assign a column to an array in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to map two excel spread sheets based on column location I am creating two separate arrays and want to know if it is possible to assign a column to an array  example

```
dim ex 1 to 2 as string

ex(1) = column("A")
ex(2) = column("B")
```

and etc.

I am in the process of implementing the two arrays

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim source As Workbook
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim dest As Workbook
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim tmp As String
Dim startCell As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastColumn As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim mapDest As String
Dim mapSrc As String
Dim data As String
Dim iRows As Integer
Dim pos As Integer

setFile = Application.GetOpenFilename   'used to open the browser window
tmp = setFile                           'store the selected file in variable tmp
Application.ScreenUpdating = False      'preventing long runtimes

If Dir(tmp) <> "" Then
Set dest = ThisWorkbook     'workbook b1 is declared as the current worksheet opened
Set source = Workbooks.Open(tmp)      'the file the user selected is opened in excel

Dim lasSheets(1 To 8) As String        'array to list the sheet names
lasSheets(1) = "L1 OVERVIEW"
lasSheets(2) = "LAS EFFL RELEASE PARAMS"
'lasSheets(3) = "L1 EAL PARAMS rev4"    'now use a rev 6 so 4 is no longer used
lasSheets(3) = "L1 EAL PARAMS"
lasSheets(4) = "L1 RAD STATUS"
lasSheets(5) = "L1 PLANT STATUS"
lasSheets(6) = "L1 CDAM"
lasSheets(7) = "L1 ERDS"
lasSheets(8) = "LAS STATE UPDATES"

Dim dataPull(1 To 8) As String          'array to map the worksheet names located in the data pull sheet
dataPull(1) = "Overview Paste"
dataPull(2) = "Eff Release Para Paste"
'dataPull(3) = "EAL Rev4 Paste" 'blank sheet now use rev 6 no longer needed
dataPull(3) = "EAL Para Paste"
dataPull(4) = "Radiological Stat Paste"
dataPull(5) = "Plant Status Paste"
dataPull(6) = "CDAM Paste"
dataPull(7) = "ERDS Paste"  ' blank sheet
dataPull(8) = "State Updates Paste"   'blank sheet

Dim lasSheetsCols(1 To 16) As String
LasSheetCols(1) = .Columns("A")                 ***is ir possible to map columns?
LasSheetCols (2) =
LasSheetCols (3)
LasSheetCols (4)
LasSheetCols (5)
LasSheetCols (6)
LasSheetCols (7)
LasSheetCols (8)
LasSheetCols (9)
LasSheetCols (10)
LasSheetCols (11)
LasSheetCols (12)
LasSheetCols (13)
LasSheetCols (14)
LasSheetCols (15)



Dim dataPullCols(1 To 9) As String


For i = 1 To 8
  mapSrc = dataPull(i)
  mapDest = lasSheets(i)
 Set sht1 = source.Sheets(mapSrc)      'set sht1 and sht2 to the source and destination worksheets
 Set sht2 = dest.Sheets(mapDest)
 lResult = Right(lastCol, 10)
 Set startCell = sht1.Range("B2")
 Set checkcell = sht1.Cells

'find last row and last column
 lastRow = sht1.Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, startCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
 lastColumn = sht1.Cells(startCell.Row, sht1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

 lastCol = sht1.Cells(sht1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column


sht1.Range(startCell, sht1.Cells(lastRow, lastColumn).Address).Copy destination:=sht2.Range("D5")       'copy and paste the data from sht1 into sht2


Application.CutCopyMode = False
pos = 5

For j = 2 To lastRow         ' for loop to loop through columns A
pos = pos + 1
With sht1
     data = Right(sht1.Cells(j, 1), 11)  'retrieve the values in the cells
      sht2.Cells(pos, 1) = data
      data = ""
      End With
   Next j



Next i                              ' loop through the indexes
source.Close True
Else                                'used to prevent a error message from popping up when the user choose to cancel selecting a file

End If
End Sub
```

when a button is pressed the data is copied from one worksheet and pasted into the other worksheet based on data that is mapped together

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a whole range to a variable:

```
Dim MyRangeValues() As Variant
MyRangeValues = Range("A:O").Value
```

Now your variable `MyRangeValues` contains the columns A to O and it can be used like

```
Debug.Print MyRangeValues(row, column)
```

to print to value of a specific cell by row/column. So for example

```
MyRangeValues(2, 3)
```

will return the value of cell `C2`.